# Help parsing JSON stream into Python with BASH and jq

Tags: ubuntu, python, json, streaming, jq

I'm decent when it comes to writing python code but BASH is fairly new to me and I'd like some guidance on picking a high level approach to achieving my goal of reading sensor data from a live streaming JSON file and processing the data in python in real time.

The setup:
I have a system running Ubuntu 18.04. This system is connected to a peripheral device which reads some sensors and streams the readings to a JSON file. In order to begin the stream I've written a simple bash script which creates a directory and starts the service.

```
sudo service my_service stop
if [ -d $LOGDIR ]; then
    echo "All data in ws_log will be erased. Continue? [Y/n]: "
    read ans
    if [ "${ans,,}" = "y" ]; then
        sudo rm -Rf $LOGDIR/*
        echo Directory cleared.
    else
        echo Exiting Script
        exit 1
    fi
else
    mkdir $LOGDIR
    echo $LOGDIR Successfully created!
fi

sudo $SERVDIR/my_service --recording-directory $LOGDIR
```

Once the service is running it prints a message to the terminal telling the user to press Ctrl+c when they are finished logging (so this service is blocking the terminal until it receives SIGINT).

I'm experimenting with using the screen command to run this in a detached screen and passing commands to it via the python subprocess module. However this seems complicated and I'm not sure the screen command is the best tool for the job here. Thoughts?

Next question:
Each object in the JSON file is a packet containing 6 samples and a timestamp. The streaming JSON file is being appended to 20 times per second. The JSON file starts with '[' then has comma delimited JSON objects. The issue is, because it is streaming, it does not have an ending ']', it ends with a comma.

So far I came up with this command which uses sed to replace the last comma in the JSON file with a ']' so that [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is able to recognize the JSON objects and writes them out formatted as one object per line.

```
sed "$ s/,/]/g" log.json | jq -c '.[]' | tail -F >> simpler_log.txt
```

However, I want this line to run continuously until my python or bash script tells it to stop. Ideally I can use tail -f 's tracking to prevent from making duplicate reads of the same line. How should I fix that? or should I be doing this part differently?

Final Question:
How would you suggest I push/pull this data into my python script?

I figure I can just count the number of lines I've already parsed and make subsequent reads like so:

```
pseudo: json.loads(log_file[last_rec_line+1:-1])
```

But I'm open to hearing any suggestions you may have for how to get the data into python efficiently.

I know there is a lot here, I really appreciate any help you may have to offer!

EDIT:
Here is a sample of the log.json input, as streamed

```
[{
    "s_data": {
        "data": [
            [
                8555103,
                8461910,
                16777215,
                0
            ],
            [
                8555205,
                8462544,
                16777215,
                0
            ],
            [
                8555096,
                8461902,
                16777215,
                0
            ],
            [
                8555263,
                8462570,
                16777215,
                0
            ],
            [
                8555098,
                8461900,
                16777215,
                0
            ],
            [
                8555281,
                8462483,
                16777215,
                0
            ]
        ],
        "interval_usec": 8333
    },
    "ts": 1570255057513
},
{
    "s_data": {
        "data": [
            [
                8555122,
                8461908,
                16777215,
                0
            ],
            [
                8555274,
                8462550,
                16777215,
                0
            ],
            [
                8555089,
                8461951,
                16777215,
                0
            ],
            [
                8555255,
                8462559,
                16777215,
                0
            ],
            [
                8555081,
                8461911,
                16777215,
                0
            ],
            [
                8555194,
                8462522,
                16777215,
                0
            ]
        ],
        "interval_usec": 8333
    },
    "ts": 1570255057563
},
```

Here is the output of simpler_log.txt

```
{"s_data":{"data":[[8556322,8463977,16777215,0],[8555709,8463977,16777215,0],[8556350,8463989,16777215,0],[8555698,8463993,16777215,0],[8556240,8463965,16777215,0],[8555644,8463958,16777215,0]],"interval_usec":8333},"ts":1570492754634}
{"s_data":{"data":[[8556304,8463955,16777215,0],[8555698,8463973,16777215,0],[8556315,8463965,16777215,0],[8555700,8463962,16777215,0],[8556281,8464029,16777215,0],[8555706,8464020,16777215,0]],"interval_usec":8333},"ts":1570492754684}
{"s_data":{"data":[[8556269,8463948,16777215,0],[8555716,8464027,16777215,0],[8556308,8463958,16777215,0],[8555658,8464075,16777215,0],[8556263,8463945,16777215,0],[8555722,8463991,16777215,0]],"interval_usec":8333},"ts":1570492754734}
{"s_data":{"data":[[8556384,8463866,16777215,0],[8555703,8464072,16777215,0],[8556343,8464003,16777215,0],[8555679,8463964,16777215,0],[8556295,8463911,16777215,0],[8555719,8464070,16777215,0]],"interval_usec":8333},"ts":1570492754784}
```

Comment: Partial answer, use tail -F to read log.json, and pipe that into sed rather than let sed read the file. The final `|tail -F` doesn't obviously do anything useful. You might need your sed to delete the first `[` and to wrap each line in `[` and `]`, but at that point I am not sure if the `jq` is adding any value. Can you show some typical lines from log.json and simpler_log.txt?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the op with sample data.

Comment: Apologies, I misread your sed command. Thank you for the data. I suggest 1. use `tail -n +0 -F log.json` to read the log. 2. Use sed to convert the data into a stream of json objects. 3. Use python to read this  - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698108  Whilst the `jq -c` makes the simpler_log.txt look nice, unless you need this I would skip it. This will give you the data in realtime to your python program. You can implement the tail -n +0 -F and the sed steps in python later, but initially I would use a unix pipeline, with the python reading from stdin and use tail and sed.

Comment: So `tail -n +0 -F json.log | sed 's/^\[{/{/;s/^},/}/' | python ...`

Comment: You have two very different questions here. To be able to accept an answer, you would have to rely on somebody being able to answer _both_. It would be better to split the single question into two since they are so different (one is about a script for managing a service, and the other is a JSON parsing question).  Also note that Python programming is generally off-topic on U&L and such questions are better asked on Stackoverflow.

Comment: As an aside (belatedly) if $LOGDIR is empty then `[ -d $LOGDIR ]` will succeed, and `sudo rm -Rf $LOGDIR/*` will become `sudo rm -Rf /*`. I would *strongly* recommend that you (a) have a test for `"$LOGDIR"` being non-empty, and (b) double-quote all uses of your variables just in case they contain whitespace or other characters relevant to a shell